# Android Studio HiAI Engine Integration Process

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Hello I am trying to integrate HiAI Engine I followed the  [official docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/android-studio-access-0000001054356828) but this error appears

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.huawei.hiai.hiai-engine:huawei-hiai-pdk:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/huawei/hiai/hiai-engine/huawei-hiai-pdk/1.0.0/huawei-hiai-pdk-1.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/huawei/hiai/hiai-engine/huawei-hiai-pdk/1.0.0/huawei-hiai-pdk-1.0.0.pom
       - https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/huawei/hiai/hiai-engine/huawei-hiai-pdk/1.0.0/huawei-hiai-pdk-1.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.huawei.hiai.hiai-engine:huawei-hiai-vision-ove:10.0.4.307.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/huawei/hiai/hiai-engine/huawei-hiai-vision-ove/10.0.4.307/huawei-hiai-vision-ove-10.0.4.307.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/huawei/hiai/hiai-engine/huawei-hiai-vision-ove/10.0.4.307/huawei-hiai-vision-ove-10.0.4.307.pom
       - https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/huawei/hiai/hiai-engine/huawei-hiai-vision-ove/10.0.4.307/huawei-hiai-vision-ove-10.0.4.307.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Comment: hi@yasser, can you please provide more information about your problem like your test device and the specific application scenario?According this we can analyze your problem and try to help.

Comment: It's a new project in android studio. the first thing that I was trying is hiai installation.

Comment: what does your build.gradle file look like?

Comment: @yasser, HiAI Engine has strongly depends on the device. if not for the KRIN970 and later chips are not available.

Comment: @Zachary 
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: @Zachary
dependencies :
`
   implementation group: 'com.huawei.hiai.hiai-engine', name: 'huawei-hiai-pdk', version: '1.0.0', ext: 'aar'
    implementation group: 'com.huawei.hiai.hiai-engine', name: 'huawei-hiai-vision-ove', version: '10.0.4.307', ext: 'aar'`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the necessary dependencies are not found in maven. Refer to this codelab and the repo link for functioning code instead. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HiAIGeneralTextRecognition/index.html#0

https://github.com/huaweicodelabs/HiAI-Engine/tree/master/HiAICode-Oversea

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer